# Access EJB from JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, ejb, jersey, jax-rs

While Developing a Java EE Web app, I would like to know simple ways to access an stateless `EJB` object  through `Rest`.

This project needs **no** Dynamic Web from Java, as Client side is fully javascript deployed, so communication is done only with `Ajax` calls.

As I've read one way would be to create 2 `EJB` one for functionality other to represent Web Service.

Is there a way to avoid the Web Service part? (avoid completely the WAR) Maybe with `DI`?

Java EE 6, EJB 3.1, Eclipse desired. I also believe the right application server would be Glassfish instead of Jboss, due to it's compatibility with `EJB` 3.0

No interesting in using `JAX-WS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EJB 3.1 you can actually publish a session bean as a JAX-RS web service, if you package your (properly annotated) session bean inside a WAR.

So, the simplest solution I can think of would be to create a WAR (a dynamic web app if you're using Eclipse) and create a JAX-RS annotated stateless session bean inside the web app. You don't need any EJB projects at all.

Comment: So if I already have an ejb-project I must create a new war project just for the rest-services?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. In Java EE 6 you can directly publish a Session Bean as a JAX-WS web service, but not as a JAX-RS web service. You're pretty much stuck with creating a WAR that hosts that JAX-RS services that front the EJBs themselves.

Comment: So in Eclipse, an EAR project with  EJB + Web modules should always be created?

Comment: I can't speak to Eclipse, as I don't use it, but that sounds appropriate to me.

Comment: From the spec: In a product that also supports EJB, an implementation MUST support use of stateless and singleton session beans as root resource classes, providers and Application subclasses. JAX-RS annotations MAY be applied to a bean’s local interface or directly to a no-interface bean.